# Estimating Sample sizes for Null Hypothesis Testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, statistical-power, effect-size

Wikipedia has the [following table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_size_determination) for computing sample sizes:

[image]

The table was generated for the following targets:

- Significance level of 0.05.
- Statistical power
- Cohen's d (i.e. the effect size)

How does one compute this table? For a given input (desired $\alpha$, power and Cohen's d), how does one compute the minimum sample size?

Is there an algebraic relationship between these quantities? Is this an inverse problem?

Also, I presume that the above assumes that both groups have the sample size $n=n_1=n_2$. Is there a similar relationship (or equation) when $n_1$ and $n_2$ are allowed to be different?

Comment: It's based on generalizing [a later section in the same Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_size_determination#By_cumulative_distribution_function) to the case of unknown $\sigma$. If you follow through that you'll see there's no conceptual or practical problem for $n_1\ne n_2$, apart from the need for much more extensive tables.